# Why is the position of my picker in the app different than in the storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout, uistoryboard

In the picture below you can see that I have placed a picker view in the storyboard above the label. However when I launch the app in the simulator you can see that the picker is more or less right on top of the label.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the picker to the position where I placed it in the storyboard?

[image: picker is "in" the label]

Comment: What size layout are you using on the storyboard, and what device are you using in the simulator?

Comment: Device: iPhone 3.5 inch - I don't know which size layout I'm using, where can I look that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and drag with mouse from label to picker view.
[image]

Select `Vertical spacing`

[image]

And that's it.